# Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters - KeyError

Tags: python, string

Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

Example 1:

```
Input: "abcabcbb"
Output: 3 
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
```

Example 2:

```
Input: "bbbbb"
Output: 1
Explanation: The answer is "b", with the length of 1.
```

Example 3:

```
Input: "pwwkew"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "wke", with the length of 3. 
             Note that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.
```

Here's my code:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        dict = {}
        b_pointer = 0
        a_pointer = 0
        maxx = 0
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] not in dict:
                dict[s[i]] = 1
                b_pointer +=1
                maxx = max(maxx,b_pointer-a_pointer)
            else:  
                del dict[s[a_pointer]]
                a_pointer +=1


        return maxx
```

**Error**: `KeyError: 'a'`

Help?

Comment: can you share the stacktrace

Comment: you are getting `KeyError` you are deleting a key which is not in the dictionary

Comment: It shouldn’t enter the else if that was the case, right?

Comment: I have added the accepted code in the edit. Please accept. :)

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `s[a_pointer]` is not present in dictionary when you are trying to delete it. Here are the instances of your dictionary at each point in your loop before it gives runtime error.

[image: dictionary]

You can see that at the last point there is no 'a' present in dictionary.
Here is the modified accepted code.

```
class Solution:
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
    dict = {}
    b_pointer = 0
    a_pointer = 0
    maxx = 0
    while a_pointer < len(s) and b_pointer < len(s):
        if s[b_pointer] not in dict:
            dict[s[b_pointer]] = 1
            b_pointer +=1
            maxx = max(maxx,b_pointer-a_pointer)
        else:  
            del dict[s[a_pointer]]
            a_pointer +=1


    return maxx
```